# Does client side hashing reduce insider risk?

Tags: authentication, passwords, hash

One of the companies I worked for used client-side hashing to minimize risk when logging the password in the server logs. Can this be a good reason to implement client-side hashing?

Comment: Why log the password at all? Now, the hash is the password.

Comment: Contrary to what everyone is saying, having the client hash the password (along with the server hashing the hashed password) can prevent an attacker from recovering the plaintext password to try on other sites. You'd still need to take the same precautions with the hashed password as the regular password.

Comment: @user contrary to what you're saying, I specifically addressed that in my answer.

Comment: @user but ideally that is something the user defends against by avoiding password reuse.

Comment: @user That client side hashing was used for this was neither stated nor implied by OP, it also has little bearing on server logs. Occam's razor says this is about very bad security practices, not some extra zealous edge case.

Comment: Are they doing this because they believe it's safe to log the hashed password? Or are they doing this defensively, in case some intermediate system *inadvertently* logs the hashed password? Once you've integrated a bunch of different telemetry and error capturing services, it's too easy to accidentally log entire HTTP request bodies. It's not OK to do that on *purpose*, but if you want to minimize the damage if it *does* happen, hashing the password on the client is a reasonable precaution. But, you're obligated to treat that hash just as securely as you treated the plaintext password.

Comment: At this day and age you should minimize risk of logging passwords by not handling it yourself at all in the first place. There are plenty of existing components implementing OAuth2/OpenID Connect that are in production at many companies and receiving some attention from security researchers, so just pick some and plug it into your application. The same is true for kerberos/gssapi, saml and other older protocols if you need those. So just use an existing authentication component and don't write it and you don't have to worry about leaking things through stupid mistakes much.

Comment: @user229044 if you'd just posted that as an answer I'd probably have upvoted it

Comment: @BenMillwood It's not an answer though, it's a request for clarification

Answer (score 20):

Almost never.

As others have pointed out, this just replaces "SECRET" with "HASH(SECRET)". To make things worse they log the hash, which is now the password.

This is because the client is authenticated on the basis of the hash it transmits, alone; so, knowing this hash either by intercepting it at the client level or by lifting it off the logs, one can access the service at any future time until the secret is changed.

These two things together **negate all logging security** and create a problem (you are now logging "*data, including personalised security credentials which can be used to carry out fraud*", and this impacts your PSD2 compliancy).

Having a *different* hash on the client (for logging purposes) and on the server (for authentication purposes) would be tricky to implement, since the server guys would have no quick way of verifying that the hash is indeed correct, unless they knew the password (which would have to be stored in the clear somewhere). Using the *same* hash or a two-level hash might be used, I don't know, to diagnose whether the password was sent correctly (the client sends both the pass and its hash, the second gets logged and is the same as the hash stored in the auth records, or is the hash of that hash just to complicate things) -- but unless things go very wrong, this information is the same as the login status.

A better way to do this would be for the server to send a unique ID plus a timestamp, and for the client to hash together the password, the unique ID and the timestamp. The server could then send ID, timestamp and username to a black-box "oracle" that would only answer yes or no (or "OK", "NO SUCH USER", "BAD PASSWORD", "TIMESTAMP EXPIRED", "UNIQUEID REUSE DETECTED" and so on). This way:

- the server does not know the password (the "oracle" does)
- the log can safely contain both unique id and timestamp
- the hash cannot be reused (the timestamp would go "stale" after some time)
- the password never travels in the clear, only the hash does
- unique id and timestamp act as salts of each other

You might be interested in looking at [thinbus-srp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/thinbus-srp).

Comment: SRP is a good approach in many cases. But we should keep in mind that the service side in such scheme cannot enforce any password policy: how often user changes the password and if changes it at all, password, length, password complexity. Everyone decides if this is important in particular case.

Comment: @mentallurg: A hacked client can always ignore password complexity by ghetto-implementing client side hash or worse.

Comment: @Joshua: It was not the point. I mean that it depends on the context. If users do really care about their safety and event don't want to trust the server, then SRP is very good. In such case not server side, but users will require using such scheme. But there are also other cases when users are less skilled and it may be reasonable to enforce some password policies. Then SRP may be not the best choice.

Comment: "These two things together actually negate all security" - If it negates all security, then it would be equivalent to not having a password for the service in the first place, which clearly isn't the case. Secondly, who ever said that client-side hashing is the only hashing involved? Thirdly, in most cases, someone with access to the server logs can usually manage the service anyway, so trying to hide hashed login creds from sysadmins is like hiding bread from the toaster. I agree that logging creds in any form is bad, but that is an issue separate from additional client-side hashing.

Comment: I don't understand why hash of a password is a password. If server hashing is different from client hashing, one hash can't be easily used to hack another.

Comment: @Luc you are correct. I have amended the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: @Basilevs I tried explaining, but the clearest and most concise explanation is in mentallurg's answer.

Comment: @LSerni I don't understand what you mean by this: "*would be tricky to implement, since the server guys would have no quick way of verifying that the hash is indeed correct, unless they knew the password*". The server should just apply another hash (doesn't matter which) on the server and compare it the same way as it would for a password. The server doesn't have to care that the client sent 25e2fccf9401ff0d9e20dbc86e2e71e4 instead of the password, since as you kind of say, that becomes the password (except that the logs/server can't possibly learn the plaintext anymore, also not in transit).

Answer (score 11):

Sending hash instead of password does not solve the problem with logs. If an attacker get access to logs and can read hashes, then knowing password becomes not necessary. In the login request the attacker will just send the hash retrieved from the log. The server will not know if the client has password and created a hash, or if the client knows only the hash.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not a good reason:

This never helps. This architecture just replaced the secret "password" with the secret "hash of password". Neither can ever fall into the wrong hands, because the hash is sufficient for logging on. (You can never assume the client has unmodified software. A simple debugger is sufficient to make a client program send whatever you want.)

And they're logging these hashes, which they simply shouldn't do, because now they've got a plaintext log of all the credentials necessary to log on.

The issue at hand is the overzealous logging, not the passwords.

Plain hashing, as far as I can tell, also doesn't ever contribute any further factors into the credentials, so I only see very strange use cases where it might be helpful (for example, to avoid password reuse vulnerabilities should the server be compromised—but if your user reuses passwords, then your server being compromised should be the least of their worries). Instead, I often see it used as snake-oil ("magical cure") for security issues that are much more severe but people try to distract from—exactly like this logging issue, or things like unencrypted database connections.

Comment: Doesnt client side hashing, with the act of authentication being the comparison of the hash result and the stored value in the authentication store, mean that the act of salting the value in the authentication store is now meaningless because you are comparing given hash (created clientside with presumably the salt) to stored hash? Which means the authentication store basically has all the authentication tokens in plain text for anyone to steal?  In other words, how do you know if the client is actually hashing a provided value or just giving you a stolen hash?

Comment: @Moo exactly, you don't So, no advantage to hashing – exactly what my last paragraph tried ot explian.

Comment: We found on analysis this does in fact help. A backdoored server can't steal the user's real password, and if each has the password client-hashed with the hostname as salt, the server can't even steal credentials that can be used on another server.

Comment: @Moo: If all hashing is done on the client, that would indeed be the case.  On the other hand, if the client is sent a salt and then asked to perform some slow hash operation that yields a 256-bit hash value, which then be fed through a secure but fast cryptographic hash, someone wanting to brute-force the server would have to search through a space of 2^256 equally likely has values, rather than searching through a space of low-entropy human-readable passwords.  I would think such an approach could mitigate denial of service attacks by reducing the effort required for each access attempt.

Comment: Your "very strange use case" is actually *literally the entire reason why password hashing exists in the first place.*  It has nothing to do with securing the site itself, because if a hacker gets access to the hashed passwords, they're already in the system and can access all sorts of other stuff; it's to protect all the stupid users out there who reuse passwords.  You shouldn't downplay its importance.

Comment: "if your user reuses passwords, then your server being compromised should be the least of their worries" -- but the reality is users *do* reuse passwords, even if you ask them not to. Might as well remove one of their worries, even if it's the least one.

Comment: @BenMillwood, Mason, you're both right, and I do agree. But that's not what was asked: "... minimize risk **when logging passwords**", not *generally*. The right solution to minimizing risk when logging passwords is *not to log passwords*. Logging hashes instead isn't the right approach.

Answer (score 2):

It won't help the client, as many others have said, because `hash(password)` is enough for a malicious party gain unwanted acess. But at least `password` won't end up in a wordlist, if the server is hacked and all the logged hashes become public.

Answer (score 2):

First let me say that you should never ***ever*** be logging passwords, but it seems from the question that the company you worked for was worried about *inadvertent* logging.  Maybe they have some kind of logging software on their server that stores all communications including when you send the password.

Simple hashing offers a *very small* level of gain.  As others have said if your client uses the hash to login, others could use the has as well, so what's the point?  The *very small* gain in security is that you won't automatically expose the raw password.  This would only help if:

1. The password is large enough to prevent discovery from the hash (using rainbow tables or brute force for instance)
2. The password is changed regularly (hash would only be usable for a short time)
3. You log the passwords ***WHICH YOU SHOULDN'T EVER EVER DO***, but from your question it seems you are worried about an accidental occurrence or if some third party or crash/error reporting software logs it carelessly

First: If someone nabs your log file and you have plaintext passwords in there, it's just game over.  Some software might log what is sent to the server without your knowledge and the log file might be placed somewhere it shouldn't be.  Yes, *in a perfect world* this would never happen, but some temp or tech support person might run across such a file some day.  If there are plaintext passwords in there, the amount of work to do something malicious is just so small it could tempt people that would never dream of cracking hashes or writing software to use your system with a hash.  "My manager's password is there?  I'm just going to login to our email client with his information quick and search for my name for what he's been saying about me..."

Second: If passwords are changed regularly, an uncrackable hash would be worthless in a few months, or on other sites.  Many people only make minimal changes to their passwords though, and re-use them on other sites.  So if your software that uses client-side hashing exposes your application because the hashes can be used, the same hashes probably can't be used for other purposes such as email or authentication to network shares or other intranet sites.  Some people probably have the same or similar passwords for other sites online like personal mail, amazon, banking, etc.  It's bad practice, but that's what a lot of hackers rely on.  If you see the password three months ago is 'Fluffy#$Kitten7', you might try 'Fluffy#$Kitten8' next since many people make minor changes to their password when they are required to change it frequently.  The hash would be completely different for the new passwords so the old one would be invalid.

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues here: **logging sensitive data** in plain files, and **password hashing**.

#### Logging sensitive data

Don't do this.

This includes passwords, other security tokens (session IDs), racial or other data labeled as sensitive under GDPR or your local jurisdiction, and other data that sysadmins don't need to help in debugging.

If you have a stupid manager that overrules you, then look into **encrypting the data** with a public key. The private key can be kept somewhere safe, like in a safe deposit box or some **offline** system. If you ever need access to the data, you can get it, but there is very little risk of anyone else decrypting that data.

Specifically for passwords: if you are going to hash them anyway, then why log it in the first place? Apparently nobody wants access to the plaintext version of it, and to reset a user account you can reset the password value in the database. There is no reason to log hashed passwords.

#### Password hashing

To see whether client-side hashing is helpful, define what the risks are and follow the logic.

You mention an insider threat, but who is that insider? Can they only read log files? Do they have database access? Can they change the code running on the server?

- If the insider can only read log files, then client-side hashing would help. If the user uses Fluffy1992! as password, then hashing prevents the insider from knowing that, so the insider can't try to login to other accounts of this user. But like others pointed out, they can login to the application by submitting whatever the original user submitted (a replay attack; this can be prevented with a challenge-response system).
- If the insider can also access the database, there would be no reason for the insider to login to the user account: they can already see and modify everything the user can. Hashing still helps not to reveal the kind of password that the user used, so it's still helpful.
- If the insider can also change the code that is running on the server, then they can change it such that the client is instructed (through a modified javascript file or malicious update) to also submit a plaintext of the password. This is extra effort and might be spotted by other visitors of the website, though, so client-side hashing would prevent opportunistic reading of passwords and feel more risky, but not actually deter a determined person.

Note that the server should always apply a quick hash to the hash that the client sends: if someone gains read-only database access (e.g. SQL injection in a `select` query, or a stolen database backup), they can read the password hash from the database but still need to break it. Without applying the hash on the server, they could take the database value as password. So the client should do `pwhash = bcrypt(password+salt,cost); send(pwhash);` and the server should do `store_in_database(sha256(pwhash))`.

---

Since your question is about logging the hash, I think the simple solution is not to log sensitive data, as said. Nevertheless, client-side hashing is not a bad idea if you also apply an additional hash on the server. Client-side hashing helped mitigate other security issues in the past, but if it had been more common, it would have prevented many more.

Comment: "The server should always apply a quick hash to the hash that the client sends" - no, the sever should apply a slow secure hash (e.g. bcrypt) to whatever the client sends, to deal with the important threat (the database leaks and an attacker tries to get credentials from it). It's the client side hashing that can be less secure, because the threat there is less important (it's vital to do server-side hashing but many people don't do client-side hashing). If an attacker has the client-side hash then that already lets them authenticate as the user, which is usually the main thing we care about.

Comment: @rlms No, the client should apply a slow secure hash (e.g. bcrypt) to whatever the user enters, to deal with the important threat (the database leaks and the attacker tries to figure out users' credentials). If you have database access to read stored credentials anyway, you already have the kingdom, why care about the keys to it? It is definitely not the main thing I see as a threat since credential re-use is *so much more* prevalent and impactful than *accessing the application after completely owning the database*.

Comment: Also, fast server-side hashing is not less secure because the token is already strengthened on the client. A slow hash makes it harder to crack a weak password: after strengthening, there is little point doing another slow hash on the server. If it sounds theoretical, try it: here's a client-side bcrypt of a bad password (3 words no spaces, ~48 bits of entropy): `$2a$12$uGO0B0bnWhrFmonzpVrHbehy6woBE6dTMRRUuwopBxirRLWb0TsiW` and here's the md5 of the hash part (`hy...`): `a25d5f675a6780eb7bccf435c934d6b4`. If you stole the weak md5 from the database, can you get to the former so you can login?

Comment: The point is that you don't need the actual password to log in, you just need whatever the client sends, because you're a l33t hacker (i.e. you can use curl to send requests with hashes to the server rather than typing in the password on the client website). If the data the client sends to authenticate is leaked (whether that's passwords or password hashes) *you've already lost*.

Comment: The client applying "a slow secure hash (e.g. bcrypt) to whatever the user enters" does **not** "deal with the important threat (the database leaks and the attacker tries to figure out users' credentials)" in any way!

Comment: @rlms why not ?

Comment: Suppose you have only client-side hashing, so you type in your password, the client hashes it to get `$2a$12$uGO0B0bnWhrFmonzpVrHbehy6woBE6dTMRRUuwopBxirRLWb0TsiW`, that gets sent to the server, and the server checks if it is equal to your password hash in the database. Then the database leaks, and I get your username and `$2a$12$uGO0B0bnWhrFmonzpVrHbehy6woBE6dTMRRUuwopBxirRLWb0TsiW`. Then I can do `curl -u username:$2a$12$uGO0B0bnWhrFmonzpVrHbehy6woBE6dTMRRUuwopBxirRLWb0TsiW https://example.com` to authenticate as you.

Comment: @rlms You didn't read my answer then. I wrote: "the server should always apply a quick hash to the hash that the client sends". You could also have read my previous comment that I specifically addressed to you: "here's a client-side bcrypt [...] and here's the md5 [...] If you stole the weak md5 from the database..." The point is that this `$2a$...siW` is not the value stored in the database, it's something else. (MD5 was chosen because sha2 would have been too long to fit in the comment; of course one should never actually use MD5. The point is that it's a fast hash, yet secure.)

Comment: What you said was "No, the *client* should apply a slow secure hash (e.g. bcrypt) to whatever the user enters, to deal with the important threat (the database leaks and the attacker tries to figure out users' credentials)." This isn't true. If the *server* uses a suitable hash function, *that* gives security against database leaks, and conversely if the server doesn't hash there is no security. That additionally doing client-side hashing changes which functions are suitable to use server-side doesn't change the fact that the security is coming from the server-side hashing.

Comment: @rlms You keep ignoring that when an attacker has access to the user credentials table, they usually don't need to use these credentials anymore to, you know, break into the application. But aside from that, how is a quick hash not suitable when what the client submits is already hashed with bcrypt?

Comment: "You keep ignoring that when an attacker has access to the user credentials table, they usually don't need to use these credentials anymore to, you know, break into the application." Nope, leaks of database backups that don't involve attackers having full access to the database server are very common.

Comment: @rlms Okay, rephrasing, you keep ignoring parts of what I write. Leaving in the middle how common backup stealing vs application vulnerabilities are, how is a quick hash not suitable when what the client submits is already hashed with bcrypt?

Comment: I was wrong to imply in my first comment that your solution is not significantly more secure than just using a quick hash on the server side. My main objection is to your apparent emphasis on client-side hashing over server-side. Perhaps it is obvious to you that server-side hashing is vital but that isn't necessarily the case for someone reading your answer. But also, your proposed scheme isn't quite equivalent to using bcrypt server-side since the salt must be public.

Comment: @rlms Salts are not secret, though, just unique. The only way client-side hashing might degrade security is through incorrect implementation, such as not hashing at all on the server side, or sending the pepper value (secret input as recommended by NIST since ~2017) to the client (instead it should be applied server-side only), that sort of thing. It might be more complex, but it's more secure rather than less.

Comment: The main purposes of a salt don't require it to be secret, but it does have an effect. If I know the salt used for your password, I can pre-compute possible bcrypt hashes for it, then after if your database leaks I only need to solve the fast server-side hash for these.

Comment: @rlms I guess that is a concern I had not thought of: some agency might want quick access and can afford to pre-compute a one-off rainbow table specific for your salt, if they know the salt of their target before they capture the hash in a separate (later) attack. Very far-fetched, but possible. But then, a pepper value (secret input) also prevents this from working, and mixing in a pepper value has been an official recommendation for a while now. It was never recommended to keep salts secret I think, so I'm not sure we should shoehorn salts into serving this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It does not, proper hashing requires iterations and salts, which with client side hashing can't be achieved (e.g. without the system knowing the salt and actual password it can't verify it). If you are just doing a normal hash, then you just replace the secret like Marcus is pointing out.

However the proper way of fixing is - is to use tokenisation or sanitisation of passwords within the logs, rather than using hashing. Tokenising and sanitising should be done for all sensitive fields ideally.

Comment: The salt is not secret, so this can't not be achieved. The client could ask for the salt or the salt could be serviceName+userName. Client-side hashing isn't rocket science (in fact, earlier today I was recounting to a friend how it saved my ass that SMF forums do client-side hashing and prevented people with my session token from invoking admin features). Of course, I do agree with the second part about simply not putting sensitive data in log files.